# Subscription Update - Google Play

Tags: flutter, google-play, in-app-purchase

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase package to manage user subscriptions.

The subscription workflow works well, but I am having the following issue during the update workflow.

I follow the recommended approach by including in `ChangeSubscriptionParam` the `PurchaseDetails` representing the original subscription.

The transaction properly goes through and Google Play Subscriptions correctly reflect the change but my purchase listener receives `PurchaseDetails` object that represent the original subscription and not the new one.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

gen

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone encounters the same issue, the reason behind the above behavior was related to `ProrationMode.deferred` mode I was using. When it is switched to the default `immediateWithTimeProration` value the correct information is returned.